# Copying data, based on the value in a cell

Tags: google-sheets

I've been trying to work out how to copy data from cells on a worksheet into another based upon the value in a cell.

We have weekly data so for arguments sake

```
Week 1     Week 2     Week 3     Week 4

   1         5          3          2

  $10       $90        $75        $15
```

What I'd like to be able to do, is input the overall worksheet with Week 1 and it automatically drags 1 and 10 into cells from the data worksheet.

I've been trying to make lookup address & vlookup work, but neither appear to do what I'd like them to... I'm using Google Docs if that makes any difference?

Comment: Perhaps you can share a doc with us or show us the outcome in a second table?

Answer (score 1):

If `Week 1` is in A1 of both sheets, `1` is in A2 of `a worksheet` etc then this might suit in B1 of `another`:

```
 =index(a!$A:$D,2,match($A1,a!1:1,0))
```

copied across to C1 and the `2` there replaced by `3`.